# Sub Query with WITH-CLAUSE in H2DB

Tags: sql, h2

I have a simple SQL query to count all Employees in a Department(within children) like:

```
With Temp(id) AS
(
        Select d.id From DEPARTMENT d 
    Where d.id = 1 
    UNION ALL
    Select d.id From DEPARTMENT d JOIN Temp te ON d.idDepartment = te.id
)
Select count(*) From 
(
    Select e.id From Employee e Join Temp te On e.idDepartment = te.id
)
```

But i give a error "StackOverflow", I dont know where is mistake, can you help me?
there are some data for test case:
**Table Department :**

```
ID----------departmentName-----------idDepartment(id parent)
1              A                         0
2              B                         1
```

**Table Employee :**

```
id----------employeeName------------idDepartment
1              E_1                       1
2              E_2                       1
3              E_3                       2
```

So when I select quantity of Eployee in a Department(A)--> result : 3, if Department B --> result: 1
Thanks!

Comment: Could you include some data as well, so that we have a reproducible test case?

Comment: thanks Thomas! I imported some data in my answer, could you show me?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution that works:

```
create table Department(id int, name varchar(255), idDepartment int);
create table Employee(id int, name varchar(255), idDepartment int);
insert into Department values(1, 'A', 0), (2, 'B', 1);
insert into Employee values(1, 'E1', 1), (2, 'E2', 1), (3, 'E3', 2);
with recursive temp(id) as (
    select 1 union all
    select d.id from temp te 
    inner join Department d on d.idDepartment = te.id
)
select count(*) from temp te 
inner join Employee e on e.idDepartment = te.id;
drop table Department;
drop table Employee;
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I moved my post to my question. I resolved this problem, thanks again!

Comment: I think if Temp inside sub query --> it not work, but outside query it work, right?