# H2DB WITH clause

Tags: sql, h2, with-statement

I'm writing a unit test for a method with the following sql

```
WITH    temptab(
i__id ,  i__name, i__effective, i__expires, i__lefttag, i__righttag,
hier_id, hier_dim_id, parent_item_id, parent_hier_id, parent_dim_id, 
ancestor, h__id, h__name, h__level, h__effective, h__expires, rec_lvl)  
AS ( 
  SELECT 
  item.id          as i__id,        
  item.name        as i__name,        
  item.effectivets   as i__effective,        
  item.expirests     as i__expires,       
  item.lefttag     as i__lefttag,     
  item.righttag    as i__righttag,       
  hier_id,        hier_dim_id,        
  parent_item_id,      
  parent_hier_id,     
  parent_dim_id,        1          as ancestor,    
  hier.id    as h__id,        hier.name  as h__name,   
  hier.level as h__level,        hier.effectivets as h__effective,    
  hier.expirests as h__expires,        1 as rec_lvl FROM   metro.item item,      
   metro.hierarchy hier  WHERE  item.id    = 'DI'     AND hier_id    = '69'     AND hier_dim_id= '36'  AND hier.id    =item.hier_id
 )
SELECT  
  i__id,    i__name,    i__effective,    i__expires,    i__lefttag,  
  i__righttag,    hier_id,    hier_dim_id,    parent_item_id,  
  parent_hier_id,    parent_dim_id,    ancestor,   
  h__id,    h__name,    h__level,    h__effective,    h__expires 
FROM temptab
```

This query returns empty dataset, but I expect 1 row.

The data are correct, as similar simple query without with clause works fine.

I investigated the problem and I've found the
[Sub Query with WITH-CLAUSE in H2DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391406/sub-query-with-with-clause-in-h2db)
but that solution did not help.

So, does anyone know how H2 supports with clause?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: h2 *only* supports recursive CTEs. It does **not** support regular CTEs

Answer (score 4):

According to the following :[h2 database grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html)

Looks like `WITH` clause is not supported in H2 database, except of experimental support for recursive queries: [h2 recursive queries](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries)

Comment: It is supported, but only for recursive queries: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries

Answer (score 2):

Its supported now http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html
For non-recursive queries also.

Comment: Where it is written?