# Is there a way to merge these three SQL queries into one?

Tags: sql, h2

I have code that is currently performing 3 SQL (H2) queries to get results and I would like it to just do one query. It is functional as it is, so the result should be the same.

The end result is a list of two columns (title and rating) of TV series recommendations based on an incoming title.

For example, if the title is "Pokemon" it returns all results that are not "Pokemon" from the `TVSERIES` table that match one or more genres from the `GENRES` table (e.g. "Cartoon" and "Comedy"), and match the classification from the `CLASSIFICATIONS` table (e.g. "Y-7"), and return the results in order of their average IMDb rating from the `IMDBRATING` table.

The first two are only there to populate the WHERE clause of the third query - the third one is the one that really does most of the work.

Query 1:

```
SELECT GENRE FROM GENRES
LEFT JOIN TVSERIES ON GENRES.TVSERIESID = TVSERIES.ID
WHERE TVSERIES.TITLE = 'A Title'
```

then I iterate over any results to create a string like `GENRES.GENRE = 'Comedy' OR GENRES.GENRE = 'Drama'` (there can be any number of rows) and store it as the variable `genresCondition`.

Query 2:

```
SELECT CLASSIFICATION FROM CLASSIFICATIONS
LEFT JOIN TVSERIES ON CLASSIFICATIONS.TVSERIESID = TVSERIES.ID
WHERE TVSERIES.TITLE = `A Title`
LIMIT 1
```

then I store that result as a string like `CLASSIFICATIONS.CLASSIFICATION = 'PG-13'` and store it as the variable `classificationCondition`.

Query 3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TVSERIES.TITLE, IMDBRATINGS.IMDBRATING
FROM TVSERIES
LEFT JOIN GENRES ON TVSERIES.ID = GENRES.TVSERIESID
LEFT JOIN IMDBRATINGS ON TVSERIES.ID = IMDBRATINGS.TVSERIESID
LEFT JOIN CLASSIFICATIONS ON TVSERIES.ID = CLASSIFICATIONS.TVSERIESID
WHERE
(genresCondition) AND
classificationCondition AND
TVSERIES.TITLE != 'A Title'
ORDER BY IMDBRATINGS.IMDBRATING DESC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the purpose of the query. It is not obvious.

Comment: I added the "For example` paragraph, hopefully that makes it more obvious

Answer (score 0):

Even H2 has a [`WITH` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696964/h2db-with-clause/26296625) nowadays, which can be used to solve your problem.

1. Use the first query, put it into the `WITH` clause.
2. Take the second second query and use the results from the first query.
3. Put everything in a second `with` clause.
4. And apply the third query.

Something similar I wrote yesterday:

```sql
with "Smartcards" as
(
  with "Modules" as
  (
    select e."Serial Number" as serno,
           m."Smartcard 1" as g1,
           m."Smartcard 2" as g2,
           m."Smartcard 3" as g3
    from   "Type 1" e,
           "Module" m
    where  e."Serial Number" = "Device Certificate Validity End"."Serial Number" and
           e."Module" = m."ID"
    union
    select r."Serial Number" as serno,
           m."Smartcard 1" as g1,
           m."Smartcard 2" as g2,
           m."Smartcard 3" as g3
    from   "Type 2" r,
           "Module" m
    where  r."Serial Number" = "Device Certificate Validity End"."Serial Number" and
           (r."Left Module" = m."ID" or r."Right Module" = m."ID")
  )
  select m.serno,
         g."RSA Certificate" as rsa,
         g."ECC Certificate" as ecc
  from   "Modules" m,
         "Smartcard" g
  where  g."ID" in (m.g1, m.g2, m.g3)
)
select min(c."Validity Not After") as "Validity Not After"
from   "Smartcards" g,
       "Certificate" c
where  c."ID" in (g.rsa, g.ecc)
```